# Angular preserve dynamic content in directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I've created a directive which is replacing button's content with loader when the input value is `true` and returns its content when the input is `false`.

The problem is that button may contain a dynamic content which is lost if the directive is applied right after rendering.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[publicLoaderBtn]'
})
export class LoaderBtnDirective implements OnChanges {
    @Input() publicLoaderBtn: boolean;
    @Input() loadingClass = 'btn__loader btn__loader--white';

    private innerHTMLTemp: string;
    private applied = false;

    constructor(
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        private el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
    ) {
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (!changes.publicLoaderBtn) {
            return;
        }

        const loading = changes.publicLoaderBtn.currentValue;

        if (!loading && this.applied) {
            this.discardLoading();
        } else if (loading && !this.applied) {
            this.applyLoading();
        }
    }

    applyLoading(): void {
        this.innerHTMLTemp = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;

        const loader: HTMLSpanElement = this.renderer.createElement('span');
        loader.classList.add(...this.loadingClass.split(' '));

        this.renderer.setProperty(
            this.el.nativeElement,
            'innerHTML',
            loader.outerHTML
        );

        this.applied = true;
    }

    discardLoading(): void {
        this.renderer.setProperty(
            this.el.nativeElement,
            'innerHTML',
            this.innerHTMLTemp
        );

        this.applied = false;
        this.innerHTMLTemp = null;
    }

}
```

And is applied like

```
<button (click)="submit()"
        [class.btn--disabled]="submitting"
        [publicLoaderBtn]="submitting"
        class="btn btn_blue mr-3">
        {{ 'buttons.approve' | translate }}
</button>
```

Here if `submitting === true` from the beginning button is empty. How can I preserve the dynamic content?

I've also been considering a structural directive but I didn't find how I can use HTML markup instead of a Component or Template ref.

Comment: Are you set on using a directive for this? If you were willing to use a component, this would be almost trivial using content projection

Comment: Yes I need to use a directive for that.

Comment: Can you expand on why you need to use a directive for this (as opposed to a `LoadingButton` component)? Also, have you considered placing the directive/component on the `button`'s content? IE `<button><span [publicLoaderBtn]>Text</span></button>`

Comment: Because there is a lot of buttons in my app that have different attributes applied and creating a component which would show and hide the text isn't that cheap to do. Nope it won't work that way.